# Is there a good working tutorial on re2c + lemon?

Tags: lemon, re2c

I've tried a couple. And there is only a couple of tutorials in Google for re2c+lemon.
Currently for all examples I get similar bunch of errors like:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
parser.y:44:5: error: ‘yygotominor’ was not declared in this scope
     A.int_value = B.int_value * C.int_value;
     ^
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
parser.c:770:16: error: ‘YY_MAX_SHIFTREDUCE’ was not declared in this scope
   if( yyact <= YY_MAX_SHIFTREDUCE ){
                ^
parser.c:771:15: error: ‘YY_MAX_SHIFT’ was not declared in this scope
     if( yyact>YY_MAX_SHIFT ) yyact += YY_MIN_REDUCE - YY_MIN_SHIFTREDUCE;
               ^
```

Where is it declared?

PS: don't post 10y old articles (even without code or if the code can't be compiled now). If you can - write an example here. If not - don't post links from Google.

Comment: My exact errors were caused by incorrect #include order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tutorial works for me:

1. Get re2c (see re2c install page for details http://re2c.org/install/install.html).
2. Get lemon: download tarball `wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/souptonuts/lemon_examples.tar.gz`, extract and build (I had to add `#include <stdlib.h>` to many examples for `malloc`).
3. Clone github repo https://github.com/tokuhirom/re2c-lemon-tutorial : `git clone https://github.com/tokuhirom/re2c-lemon-tutorial.git`
4. Patch re2c-lemon-tutorial/Makefile to find lemon and re2c (if needed).
5. `make`, `./mycalc` and enjoy (hit `Ctrl+D` to stop and emit result).

More re2c examples on re2c website: http://re2c.org, more lemon examples inside of lemon tarball.

Comment: None of these links have a small working example of using re2c + lemon that can be even compiled (Even that shit from 2008). And you know what.. surprize... I don't want to look into a CAD system to learn how to get CALC compiled correctly. You helped a lot.

Comment: I've updated the answer (this time I checked it works). :)